# How can send invitation to friends in Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-invite

I need to send invitation to my friends in facebook and save in app data about who was invited.
I tried to do it by default Facebook dialog like this:

```
WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(activity,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
```

But I cannot get list of friends who was invited.

Can I get a list of people invited? or is there another way to make an invitation?

Comment: No, you won't know who the user invited. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has revised their policies now. You can´t get the whole friendlist anyway if your App does not have a Canvas implementation and if your App is not a game. Of course there´s also taggable_friends, but that one is for tagging only.

You will be able to pull the list of friends who have authorised the app only.

See link below

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app